# Prevent wmic.exe from writing TempWmicBatchFile.bat

Tags: java, virtual-keyboard, temporary-files, wmic, on-screen-keyboard

I want to check within my Java application whether the windows virtual keyboard is already running or not.

I searched for it and found, that I can use `wmic.exe` to search for a process.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
    .getInputStream()));
OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc
    .getOutputStream());
oStream .write("process where name='osk.exe' get caption");
oStream .flush();
oStream .close();
input.readLine();
while ((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (in.contains("osk.exe")) {
        input.close();
        proc.destroy();
        return;
    }
}
input.close();
proc.destroy();
```

This is working, but `wmic` is somehow creating the file `TempWmicBatchFile.bat` with the line `process where name='osk.exe' get caption`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid opening other stream for passing another command. This is the reason why temp bat file is getting created.

Use the below code. It won't create temp batch file

```
public class WmicTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe process where name='osk.exe' get caption");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
                .getInputStream()));
//        OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc
//                .getOutputStream());
//        oStream.write("process where name='osk.exe' get caption");
//        oStream.flush();
 //       oStream.close();
        input.readLine();
        String in;
        while ((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
            if (in.contains("osk.exe")) {
                System.out.println("Found");
                input.close();
                proc.destroy();
                return;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        proc.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :)